# Взаимодействие с БД Postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

Работаю с формой, на форме выполняются результаты выполнения запросов, но в самой бд никаких изменений. Также не работает запрос на вывод данных бд за условием. С чем может связана причина? Или библиотеки psycopg2 не достаточно здесь и нужно искать решения с помощью SQLAlchemy?

```
 def connect_to_database(self):
    try:
        self.conn = psycopg2.connect(**self.db_params)
        print("Connected to the database.")
        return self.conn
    except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
        print(f"Error while connecting to PostgreSQL: {error}")
        return None
    def select_data(self):
    self.set_column_widths()

    table_entry = self.tables_combobox.get()
    text_field_entry = self.query_text_field.get("1.0", "end-1c")

    if text_field_entry == "WHERE":
        self.cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM {table_entry}")
        result = self.cursor.fetchall()
    else:
        sql_query = f"SELECT * FROM {table_entry} {text_field_entry}"
        print(sql_query)
        self.cursor.execute(sql_query)
        result = self.cursor.fetchall()

    if result:
        self.data_grid.delete(*self.data_grid.get_children())
        for row in result:
            self.data_grid.insert("", "end", values=list(row))

def delete_data(self):
    self.set_column_widths()
    table_name = self.tables_combobox.get()

    selected_index = self.data_grid.selection()[0]
    selected_item = self.data_grid.item(selected_index)
    selected_values = selected_item['values']

    if not self.data_grid.selection():
        messagebox.showwarning("Попередження", "Будь ласка, виберіть рядок для оновлення.")
        return

    query = f"DELETE FROM {table_name} WHERE id = {selected_values[0]}"
    try:
        self.cursor.execute(query)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

    self.data_grid.delete(selected_index)

def update_data(self):
    self.set_column_widths()
    table_name = self.tables_combobox.get()

    if not self.data_grid.selection():
        messagebox.showwarning("Попередження", "Будь ласка, виберіть рядок для оновлення.")
        return

    index = self.data_grid.selection()[0]
    id_value = self.data_grid.item(index)['values'][0]

    new_values = []
    for entry in self.entries:
        value = entry.get()
        if isinstance(value, str):
            new_values.append(f"'{value}'")
        else:
            new_values.append(str(value))

    query = f"UPDATE {table_name} SET {', '.join([f'{col}={val}' for col, val in zip(self.data_grid['columns'], new_values)])} WHERE id = {id_value}"
    self.cursor.execute(query)

    self.data_grid.item(index, values=new_values)

def add_data(self):
    self.set_column_widths()
    table_name = self.tables_combobox.get()

    new_values = []
    for entry in self.entries:
        value = entry.get()
        if isinstance(value, str):
            new_values.append(f"'{value}'")
        else:
            new_values.append(str(value))

    query = f"INSERT INTO {table_name} ({', '.join(self.data_grid['columns'])}) VALUES ({', '.join(new_values)})"
    self.cursor.execute(query)

    self.data_grid.insert("", "end", values=new_values)
```